# Can't enter non-ascii characters in terminal under xfce

Tags: linux, xfce, xfce4, xfce4-terminal

I use fcitx as my IME. I can use it normally in most graphical applications, but I can't submit my selection when using a terminal. The candidates window would show up as I type, but after I press space, nothing is entered.

I also cannot copy text containing CJK characters or symbols like `►`. If I copy `hi ►` and paste in the terminal, nothing is entered.

I tried this in both xterm and xfce4-terminal.

And I can't even turn IME on in text mode (Ctrl+Alt+F2).

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. My original locale was blank. It must be set to `xxx.UTF-8` for the terminals to support non-ASCII characters.

To enable Unicode support,

1. Add a line to `/etc/locale.gen` that says `en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8`
2. Run `locale-gen`
3. Add `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` to `/etc/locale.conf`
4. Reboot

Then you can check your new locale with `locale`.

Comment: Plasma uses a private locale config `~/.config/plasma-localerc`.